# Sitecore field for selecting multiple files from media library with the ability to upload files

Tags: sitecore

I'm looking for something that allow content editors to select multiple files from the media library, which will be listed in a rendering. They also need to be able upload files and to search. It has to work in the Page Editor (named Experience Editor in version 8).

What I have have considered so far:

- A bunch of File fields - but I don't know how many files the editor need to select at most, and having something like 20 similar fields seems bad.
- Using a field that supports multiple items like a Treelist with the datasource set to the Media Library allows the user to select files in an acceptable way but not uploading. I tested adding one File field just for the upload function, but was not really satisfied.

[image: Treelist and File-field]

Notes:

- Currently using Sitecore 7.5 but moving to 8 in a few days, so a solution working in Sitecore 8 is preferred.
- I have asked the Sitecore support too and will update here if I get useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the winner is.... the answer from Sitecore support:

In the [Email Experience Manager](https://doc.sitecore.net/Products/Email_Experience_Manager) module there is a field called "File List".
The image shows the dialog in Sitecore 8 and the field itself (below). It has search, supports multiple files and upload. It stores the value as pipe-separated GUIDs (just as similar fields like Treelist).

[image: Screenshot of "File List" field in Sitecore 8]

Comment: Looks good, and great that Sitecore this datatype maintenance because these GUI things or often breaks on upgrades.

Comment: Is this solution only for Sitecore 8? Additionally, this is quite a drastic movement (installing ECM) for a single field?

Comment: @PirateKitten I have not checked previous versions to 8. We are currently implementing our first Sitecore installation and we now use version 8. Also we already had EXM installed so for us it was no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use a placeholder and a file component with a DataSource.

Give the component a standard File Field. So upload is possible.
But for every new file the editor must add a new component to the placeholder with the page editor. This is with a lot of files more work for the editor. But a standard solution. (and the ability to personalize the files with the rules engine)

Comment: Yes... I thought of some iterator but of course a placeholder will do that. I will test and see if it's good enough.

Comment: A problem with this solution is that the file-reference only get stored in the rendering(?) and the rendering is (according to my tests) not handled by the version management. I.e. it is impossible to restore when the editor does something wrong.

Comment: The file reference is stored in an item, In the Renderings the reference to the sublayout and datasource are stored. The renderings field is shared so your are correct it can restore by change the version.. But in Sitecore 8 there is a new option the Final renderings with that non shared field it can be done.

Comment: I would like the links to follow the version management of the "original" item, not a new item on itself. Stored in the same way as with a treelist would be really nice (i.e. pipe-separated guids in one field) but then the renderings would need really modified code I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The [Field Types Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Field_Types.aspx) on Sitecore Marketplace includes "Visual List" and "Carousel" custom field types which may provide what you need.  I have used this in the past and found it to work well, though I'm not sure if it's compatible with Sitecore 8.  As I remember, I don't think they provided the option for uploading new media from the field.

Comment: The documentation on [sitecore market](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Field_Types.aspx) says nothing about uploading so I will try other options first, but it seems nice for other things we may want to accomplish.